Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/apps/kafkaprodute/main',?
Well, I'm getting an error that I've been trying to resolve for more than 3 hours, I want my application to upload both the API gateway and the Kafka microservice, but I'm getting this error:
2024-04-26 13:47:03 Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/apps/kafkaprodute/main'
2024-04-26 13:47:03     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
2024-04-26 13:47:03     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
2024-04-26 13:47:03     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
2024-04-26 13:47:03     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

my codes
docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3'
services:
  kafka:
    container_name: initKafka
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./apps/kafka/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app 
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run start:dev kafka 
    
  kafkaprodute:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./apps/kafkaprodute/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '4000:5000'
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app 
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run start:dev kafkaprodute 
    
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  postgres_admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '15432:80'

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - '22181:2181'

  kafkaServer:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafkaServer
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

my nest cli:
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/kafkaprodute/src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "webpack": false,
    "tsConfigPath": "apps/kafkaprodute/tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  "monorepo": true,
  "root": "./",
  "projects": {
    "kafkaprodute": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/kafkaprodute",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/kafkaprodute/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/kafkaprodute/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    },
    "kafka": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/kafka",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/kafka/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/kafka/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    },
    "lib": {
      "type": "library",
      "root": "libs/lib",
      "entryFile": "index",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/lib/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "libs/lib/tsconfig.lib.json"
      }
    }
  }
}

my dockerfile(same for both):
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

my package.json (if necessary)
{
  "name": "kafkaprodute",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"apps/**/*.ts\" \"libs/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/apps/kafkaprodute/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./apps/kafkaprodute/test/jest-e2e.json",
    "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-esm --dataSource ./dist/apps/kafka/apps/kafka/src/db/data-source-cli.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.2.2",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^2.0.5",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^10.3.7",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.2",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/kafkajs": "^1.9.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "cache-manager": "^5.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.1",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "helmet": "^7.1.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "kafkajs": "^2.2.4",
    "pg": "^8.11.5",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.20",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/apps/",
      "<rootDir>/libs/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^y/lib(|/.*)$": "<rootDir>/libs/lib/src/$1"
    }
  }
}

I can't see an error in my codes, does anyone know the solution?

What is supposed to produce the dist directory?  Does it exist on your host system?

the dist folder? yeah, exists, I have to put first before apps/ ?

Exists where; what creates it?  Because of your volumes: setup nothing in your images is actually getting used.
